# Setting x and y indexes in pySpark dataframe plot

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a pySpark dataframe on which I apply some SQL queries and want to plot the results.

```
state_grouped = "SELECT customer_state, AVG(review_score), SUM(review_score), AVG(order_products_value) FROM global_temp.olist_table GROUP BY customer_state ORDER BY AVG(review_score) DESC"

spark.sql(state_grouped).show()
```

[image]

To plot this, I convert it to pandas dataframe using `toPandas` and then do a `plot`

```
spark.sql(state_grouped).toPandas().plot(kind='barh', figsize=(12,11), logx=True)
```

The resulting diagram looks like below:

[image]

As you see in the y - axis, the indexes are basically numbers representative of the `customer_state` column. Instead of those numbers, I want to show the actual `customer_state` such as `PR`, `SP` etc.

How do I do that?

I know if I were using `pd.Dataframe` to convert to pandas dataframe, I could specify `index=['PR','SP',...]` but since I am using `.toPandas` instead, I am not sure a way to specify the actual Y axis indexes.

Can anyone please suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the ".set_yticklabels" and for that you need the y tick labels as a list which can be done by getting the column you want to be the y tick labels:

```
ylabels = example_df.select("Example_Col").rdd.flatMap(list).collect()
```

Then you can set the y ticks labels

```
example_df.toPandas().plot(kind='barh', figsize=(12,11), logx=True).set_yticklabels(ylabels)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
ax = spark.sql(state_grouped).toPandas().plot(kind='barh', figsize=(12,11), logx=True)
ax.set_xlabel("x label")
ax.set_ylabel("y label")
```

or if you looking in one line code

```
spark.sql(state_grouped).toPandas().plot(kind='barh', figsize=(12,11), logx=True).set(xlabel="x label", ylabel="y label")
```

it should be something like :
[image]

you can also add a title on your plot by addind 'title' parameter in your code :

```
spark.sql(state_grouped).toPandas().plot(kind='barh', figsize=(12,11), title='My Plot', logx=True).set(xlabel="x label", ylabel="y label")
```

the output will be :

[image]

Comment: No, thats not the question is. My question is instead of 4,5,6 etc on Y axis, how can I see the state names like PR, SP etc.